# Launch a select menu (BASH script) from the GUI with a certain keystroke

Tags: linux, bash, shell, user-interface

I've put together a shell script with a select menu that is launched from the command line. Do you guys have any ideas how I could launch it from the GUI with a certain key stroke?

I was thinking about finding a way to launch the script immediately after switching to one of the virtual terminals. (ctr-alt-f1). Is something like this possible?

GUI Shell script options seem very limited.

Comment: Please, edit your question removing all unnecessary information. This site is for "general" questions. Make your question the more general possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LXDE, you can bind actions to key combinations. See [Bindings](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aBindings) in Openbox Help.

Comment: Done! I used that and xterm to launch my script. Thanks for the help Choroba

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use virtual terminal (without LXDE), you can edit `/etc/init/tty6.conf` and change the `exec` line at the end to your script.

```
# tty6 - getty
#
# This service maintains a getty on tty6 from the point the system is
# started until it is shut down again.

start on runlevel [23] and not-container

stop on runlevel [!23]

respawn
exec /path/to/your/script
```

Comment: Is there a way I can launch it back to the GUI when the script exits?